# get information from a php page into a div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, load

i would like to use ajax to retrieve information from a php page that will update "onchange" of a select drop down menu. (`<select>`). i used jquery to check if it is changed

```
$('#names').change(function() {
   //code to get the info into the div comes here
})
```

all id like to do is work the page `"check.php"` with `"?v=valueOfNamesGoesHere"`
and return the information into the div names `"output"`
I have tried

```
$('#names').change(function() {
$('#output').load('check.php?v=' + $('#names').val());
});
```

without success. I have checked the `"check.php"` itself with the information that is supposed to get passed into it. for example `"check.php?v=john"` and i got the information needed in the page itself. (when i go directly to mysite.com/check.php?v=john).

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're doing doesn't look like [conventional AJAX methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me:_Using_Ajax) with jQuery.

Comment: Is the page that you're making this ajax call located on the same domain as your check.php code?

Comment: @Shmiddty yes, it is all located on the root for now (2 files)

Comment: what is check.php outputting (as far as HTML markup goes)?

Comment: @Shmiddty it is echoing another select list that is dynamic effected by the first select list (names). for example for john, there are 3 lastnames that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$('#names').find(":selected").text()
```

instead of `$('#names').val()` as it is a dropdown..